# How do I troubleshoot an IPsec tunnel (from a cellular router to a public server)?

Tags: vpn, ipsec, cellular

I'm new to IPsec and struggling with a setup that might soon be widely used in our operations (provided I do understand it, eventually...).

A cellular router (blackbox by netModule, from its log messages it seems to be running Linux and OpenSwan) connects a sensor network on customers' sites with our public server. We need to be able to connect into the local network, so I had the cell provider give me a public IP (a dynamic one). The way their setup works, the public IPs only allow IPsec traffic.

I set up OpenSwan on our Ubuntu server (running Jaunty). This is my connection config from `/etc/ipsec.conf`:

```
conn gprs-field-devices
    left=my.pub.lic.ip
    leftid=@vpngate.econemon.com
    #leftsubnet=192.168.1.129/25
    right=%any
    rightid=@field.econemon.com
    #rightsubnet=192.168.1.1/25
    #rightnexthop=%defaultroute
    auto=add
```

On the router, all I have is the Web UI, in which I made the following settings:

- "Remote endpoint": public IP of server, same as "left" above
- "Local Network Address": 192.168.1.1
- "Local Network Mask": 255.255.255.128
- "Remote Network Address": 192.168.1.129
- "Remote Network Mask": 255.255.255.128

The pluto process on the server is listening for connections on port 500. It can't open a tunnel, obviously, because it doesn't know at which IP the client is.

I set up a passphrase as PSK for `@field.econemon.com` in `/etc/ipsec.secrets` and also configured it in the router (which doesn't seem to support certificates).

My problem is, nothing happens. The router just says, IPsec is "down". When I copy-paste the IP into `ipsec.conf` (for "right="), and ask the server to `ipsec auto --up gprs-field-devices`, it just hangs until I press `Ctrl-C`.

Is there anything wrong with my setup? How can I debug this further?

My router gives the following loglines that seem related, but don't tell *me* anything:

> Feb 21 23:08:20 Netbox authpriv.warn pluto[2497]: loading secrets from "/etc/ipsec.secrets"
>
> Feb 21 23:08:20 Netbox authpriv.warn pluto[2497]: loading secrets from "/etc/ipsec.d/hostkey.secrets"
>
> Feb 21 23:08:20 Netbox authpriv.warn pluto[2497]: loading secrets from "/etc/ipsec.d/netbox0.secrets"
>
> Feb 21 23:08:20 Netbox authpriv.warn pluto[2497]: "netbox00" #1: initiating Main Mode
>
> Feb 21 23:08:20 Netbox daemon.err ipsec__plutorun: 104 "netbox00" #1: STATE_MAIN_I1: initiate
>
> Feb 21 23:08:20 Netbox daemon.err ipsec__plutorun: ...could not start conn "netbox00"
>
> Feb 21 23:08:22 Netbox authpriv.warn pluto[2497]: packet from 188.40.57.4:500: ignoring informational payload, type NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN
>
> Feb 21 23:08:22 Netbox authpriv.warn pluto[2497]: packet from 188.40.57.4:500: received and ignored informational message
>
> Feb 21 23:08:28 Netbox user.warn parrot.system_controller[762]: IPSECCTRLR: Tunnel 0 is down for 0 seconds
>
> Feb 21 23:08:40 Netbox user.warn parrot.system_controller[762]: IPSECCTRLR: Tunnel 0 is down for 10 seconds
>
> Feb 21 23:08:52 Netbox authpriv.warn pluto[2497]: packet from 188.40.57.4:500: ignoring informational payload, type NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN

Answer (score 2):

Some initial thoughts:

- Are the leftsubnet, rightsubnet and rightnexthop entries commented out on purpose?
- leftsubnet and rightsubnet should be network addresses, not node addresses.
- left and right should be the public IP addresses of the devices. %any is fine for the right address.
- the leftid and rightid are what the vpn devices are going to advertise themselves as. Sometimes this is their public IP address. It depends on the device.

A good place to start is the [ipsec.conf man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ipsec.conf), which gives some good info on setup.

`ipsec whack --status` is also a good command to know when troubleshooting openswan. [Here is it's man page.](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ipsec_pluto)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll update later with my current status.